# Can't upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 because "reboot required" error never goes away (even after a reboot)

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I can't upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 because it complains that a reboot is needed.  But after rebooting, the same error message is displayed again.

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS"

$ sudo apt update
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
You have not rebooted after updating a package which requires a reboot. Please reboot before upgrading.

$ uptime
 13:13:17 up 0 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.01

$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs | wc -l
480

$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs | head -n 10
linux-image-3.2.0-34-generic
linux-base
linux-image-3.2.0-35-generic
linux-base
linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic
linux-base
linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic
linux-base
libssl1.0.0
linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic

$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs | tail -n 10
linux-base
libssl1.0.0
linux-base
libssl1.0.0
linux-base
libssl1.0.0
linux-base
linux-base
linux-base
linux-base

$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           597M  8.2M  589M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.2G  5.8G  3.0G  67% /
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.0G     0  3.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       257G  220G   24G  91% /usr/local/nfsen/profiles-data
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           597M     0  597M   0% /run/user/1002
```

Comment: @user68186: Yes, but still it's a valid question.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is supported until April 30, 2021, which is why I am updating this system now.

Comment: That's a lot of kernels. Try removing some with a `sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: I agree, it's 5-years of kernel upgrades!  :)   But that command didn't do anything:


$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: I see `sudo apt upgrade` but no `sudo apt full-upgrade` ; did you perform that?

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the idea.  That command completes with no upgrades needed, and the same problem still exists.

Comment: Do you have any PPA in the sources list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you have a file `/var/run/reboot-required` and if yes, delete it.

Comment: Yes, I do have that file.  I deleted it and tried the "do-release-upgrade" and it failed with the same error.  I then rebooted and tried the upgrade and got the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: There is a second file called "/var/run/reboot-required.pkg".  When I deleted this file, the upgrade would start successfully.  Thanks for the help, and hopefully this post will help someone else!

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04, the two files to delete are `/run/reboot-required` and `/run/reboot-required.pkgs`